# How to do dot product in Rust using ndarray?

Tags: rust

I have a vector, I reshaped it to 2D array using ndarray crate. Now I wanted to do a dot product with a column vec. An example,

```
use ndarray::*;

pub fn main() {

    let vec1 = //Read from file
    let vec2 = //Read from file
    let mat = Array2::from_shape_vec((row, cols), vec1).unwrap();
    let final_mat = mat.dot(&vec2);
}
```

I get below error,

```
the trait `ndarray::linalg::impl_linalg::Dot<std::vec::Vec<f32>>` is not implemented for 
`ndarray::ArrayBase<ndarray::data_repr::OwnedRepr<i16>, ndarray::dimension::dim::Dim<[usize; 2]>>`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error has all the information you need: the trait `Dot<Vec<f32>>`, which represents the ability to call the `.dot()` method with an argument of type `&Vec<f32>`, is not implemented for `Array2<i16>`.

You need to convert `vec2` to a type `T` for which `Array2<i16>` implements `Dot<T>`.

According to the [documentation for the `Dot` trait](https://docs.rs/ndarray/0.13.1/ndarray/linalg/trait.Dot.html):

```rust
impl<A, S, S2> Dot<ArrayBase<S2, Dim<[usize; 1]>>> for ArrayBase<S, Ix2> where
    S: Data<Elem = A>,
    S2: Data<Elem = A>,
    A: LinalgScalar,
```

Which, with the fancy types simplified, means that `Array2<T>` implements `Dot<Array1<T>>`. This also means that the element types of the two arrays need to be the same, but at the moment `vec1` consists of `i16`s and `vec2` consists of `f32`s.

Solution: convert `vec2` to an `Array1` and make the elements of `vec1` `f32`s.

```rust
use ndarray::{Array1, Array2};

fn main(){
    let vec1 = // read from file, converting i16s to f32s
    let vec2 = // read from file
    let mat = Array2::from_shape_vec((row, cols), vec1).unwrap();
    let col_vec = Array1::from(vec2);
    let final_mat = mat.dot(&col_vec);
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) The message was too big and hence, I couldn't understand